# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre diferentes conversiones de string?

Tags: c#, string, conversión-de-tipos

Hace tiempo trabajaba en un proyecto en el cual siempre recibía error "Null" al ejecutarse un loop foreach, sabía donde estaba el problema pero no estaba muy seguro de como solucionarlo. EL problema acabó cuando cambie "micodigo.ToString()" a "Convert.ToString(micodigo)", y quisiera saber cuál es la diferencia entre .ToString(); Convert.ToString(); (String).micodigo; y otros mas que he visto, y como saber donde aplicar cada cual.

No recuerdo muy bien como estaba el código pero era algo así

```
private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                    if (comboBox1.Text == Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value))
                    {
                        row.Selected = true;
                    }   
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Convert.ToString(micodigo)` convierte `micodigo` a su equivalente en `string`

Si `micodigo` es `null` retorna `null`. Esto sucede porque el método `ToString()` de la clase `Convert` admite valores nulos y los maneja apropiadamente.

`micodigo.toString()` también convierte `micodigo` a su equivalente en `string`, sin embargo, si `micodigo` es `null` obtienes `NullReferenceException`

No es posible invocar un método de una referencia nula, por eso se produce esa excepción. Puedes leer sobre ello [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Por último `(String) micodigo` es aplicar un casteo y el casteo se produce en runtime.

Generalmente vas a preferir utilizar `Convert.ToString()` para evitar `NullReferenceException`o errores en tiempo de ejecucion

Answer (score 1):

La diferencia es bastante simple. Cuando haces el llamado a `.ToString()` haces el llamado a una funcion de un Objeto (Object) y se presume o se asume que ese objeto no deberia ser `null`. Mientras que cuando haces la conversion `Convert.ToString()` es un metodo que no evalua si es `null` o no, solo intenta hacer la conversion de dato. Cuando este metodo recibe `null` como valor, devuelve un `String.Empty`

Answer (score 1):

Si se declara una variable de cadena y no asigna ningún valor, por defecto se toma un valor blanco o nulo en sí, en este caso .ToString() debe lanzar una excepción de referencia nula y en Convert.ToString() nuestro programa no lanza ninguna excepción. por defecto se toma un valor en blanco en lugar de null.

```
Object obj = null;
String objValue1 = obj.ToString(); //throws Null reference exception
String objValue2 = Convert.ToString(obj);  //returns NULL
```